# Parsing a column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to take the information that is in a column that is separated by commas and select certain pieces. For example the column looks like:

(500, 411, 130, 816)

I want to be able to pull certain values, like the 500 out, in any instance that it occurs.

I've tried to pass the code through a CSV through a data frame to select out the columns I want which works but when I tried to then pass the new dataframe through and narrow the information, I still got all of the same info.

```
def parseFaultCodes(self):
        #df = pandas.read_csv('modified_example.csv')
        #faultCodes = df[(df.RDR == 514)]
        #faultCodes.to_csv('selected_codes.csv')
```

That code is what I tried but it still just returns all of the same information that I had before rather than finding any instance of 514.

Comment: can you provide an example csv and example of what the output should look like.

Comment: Maybe regex will help: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible approach, using the generic `Series.apply`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id':['A1','A2','A3'],
     'A1':['(500, 600, 700)','(510, 610, 710)','(520, 620, 720)']
})

df['A1_0'] = df.A1.apply(lambda x: x.replace('(','').replace(')','').split(',')[0])
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: With this method would it always pull out the information listed first in the column or is there a way to customize it search for certain values?

Comment: yes, to pull the 3rd element replace `split(',')[0]` with  `split(',')[2]` since the `split` puts each element into a list